# How to read s3 rasters with accompanying ".aux.xml" metadata file using rasterio?

Tags: amazon-s3, gdal, rasterio

Suppose a GeoTIFF raster on a S3 bucket which has - next to the raw TIF file - an associated `.aux.xml` metadata file:

```
s3://my_s3_bucket/myraster.tif
s3://my_s3_bucket/myraster.tif.aux.xml
```

I'm trying to load this raster directly from the bucket using rasterio:

```
fn = 's3://my_s3_bucket/myraster.tif'
with rasterio.Env(session, **rio_gdal_options):
     with rasterio.open(fn) as src:
          src_nodata = src.nodata
          scales = src.scales
          offsets = src.offsets
          bands = src.tags()['bands']
```

And this seems to be a problem. The raster file itself is successfully opened, but because rasterio did not automatically load the associated `.aux.xml`, the metadata was never loaded. Therefore, no band tags, no proper scales and offsets.

I should add that doing exactly the same on a local file does work perfectly. The `.aux.xml` automatically gets picked up and all relevant metadata is correctly loaded.

Is there a way to make this work on s3 as well? And if not, could there be a workaround for this problem? Obviously, metadata was too large to get coded into the TIF file. Rasterio (GDAL under the hood) generated the `.aux.xml` automatically when creating the raster.

Comment: `rasterio.open` appears to take a filename or file like object, so you should be able to pass it "Body" from a call to `s3.get_object()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. It appears to be essential that in the GDAL options passed to the `rasterio.Env` module, **`.xml` is added as an allowed extension to `CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS`**:

The [documentation](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS) of this option states:

> Consider that only the files whose extension ends up with one that is listed in CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS exist on the server.

And while almost all examples to be found online only set `.tif` as allowed extension because it can dramatically speed up file opening, any `.aux.xml` files are not seen by rasterio/GDAL.

So in case we expect there to be associated `.aux.xml` metadata files with the `.tif` files, we have to change our example to:

```
rio_gdal_options = {
    'AWS_VIRTUAL_HOSTING': False,
    'AWS_REQUEST_PAYER': 'requester',
    'GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN': 'FALSE',
    'CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS': '.tif,.xml',  # Adding .xml is essential!
    'VSI_CACHE': False
}

with rasterio.Env(session, **rio_gdal_options):
     with rasterio.open(fn) as src:  # The associated .aux.xml file will automatically be found and loaded now
          src_nodata = src.nodata
          scales = src.scales
          offsets = src.offsets
          bands = src.tags()['bands']
```